# Handling C# XML Deserialization with Namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, namespaces

I have been wrestling with deserializing the following XML document:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:settings xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:sl="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/schemaLibrary/2006/main" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15">
    <w:zoom w:percent="100"></w:zoom>
    <w:proofState w:spelling="clean" w:grammar="clean"></w:proofState>
    <w:defaultTabStop w:val="720"></w:defaultTabStop>
    <w:characterSpacingControl w:val="doNotCompress"></w:characterSpacingControl>
    <w:compat>
        <w:compatSetting w:name="compatibilityMode" w:uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word" w:val="15"></w:compatSetting>
        <w:compatSetting w:name="overrideTableStyleFontSizeAndJustification" w:uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word" w:val="1"></w:compatSetting>
        <w:compatSetting w:name="enableOpenTypeFeatures" w:uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word" w:val="1"></w:compatSetting>
        <w:compatSetting w:name="doNotFlipMirrorIndents" w:uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word" w:val="1"></w:compatSetting>
        <w:compatSetting w:name="differentiateMultirowTableHeaders" w:uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word" w:val="1"></w:compatSetting>
    </w:compat>
    <w:rsids>
        <w:rsidRoot w:val="00B31FC7"></w:rsidRoot>
        <w:rsid w:val="00251096"></w:rsid>
        <w:rsid w:val="00481AA7"></w:rsid>
        <w:rsid w:val="005C6856"></w:rsid>
        <w:rsid w:val="00661DE2"></w:rsid>
        <w:rsid w:val="00984D97"></w:rsid>
        <w:rsid w:val="00A06ADC"></w:rsid>
        <w:rsid w:val="00B31FC7"></w:rsid>
    </w:rsids>
    <m:mathPr>
        <m:mathFont m:val="Cambria Math"></m:mathFont>
        <m:brkBin m:val="before"></m:brkBin>
        <m:brkBinSub m:val="--"></m:brkBinSub>
        <m:smallFrac m:val="0"></m:smallFrac>
        <m:dispDef></m:dispDef>
        <m:lMargin m:val="0"></m:lMargin>
        <m:rMargin m:val="0"></m:rMargin>
        <m:defJc m:val="centerGroup"></m:defJc>
        <m:wrapIndent m:val="1440"></m:wrapIndent>
        <m:intLim m:val="subSup"></m:intLim>
        <m:naryLim m:val="undOvr"></m:naryLim>
    </m:mathPr>
    <w:themeFontLang w:val="en-US"></w:themeFontLang>
    <w:clrSchemeMapping w:bg1="light1" w:t1="dark1" w:bg2="light2" w:t2="dark2" w:accent1="accent1" w:accent2="accent2" w:accent3="accent3" w:accent4="accent4" w:accent5="accent5" w:accent6="accent6" w:hyperlink="hyperlink" w:followedHyperlink="followedHyperlink"></w:clrSchemeMapping>
    <w:shapeDefaults>
        <o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026"></o:shapedefaults>
        <o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
            <o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1"></o:idmap>
        </o:shapelayout>
    </w:shapeDefaults>
    <w:decimalSymbol w:val="."></w:decimalSymbol>
    <w:listSeparator w:val=","></w:listSeparator>
    <w15:chartTrackingRefBased></w15:chartTrackingRefBased>
    <w15:docId w15:val="{23720E07-DD19-46BC-8098-ED32713AB32B}"></w15:docId>
</w:settings>
```

I am only interested in what is contained within the rsids element. So I thought I could create classes that looked like this:

```
 [XmlRoot(ElementName ="settings", Namespace = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main")]
    public class rsids
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName ="rsids",Namespace = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main")]
        public List<rsid> Rsids { get; set; }
    }

    public class rsid
    {
        [XmlAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main")]
        public static string val { get; set; }
    }
```

I am attempting to deserialize like this:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(file);
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xdoc.ToString()))
        {
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(rsids));
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);
                rsids SettingsXml = (rsids)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(sr);

                foreach (var rsid in SettingsXml.Rsids)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(rsid.val.Count());
                }

                Console.ReadLine();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

However, I am getting the following error: "Value cannot be null". This is my first attempt at deserializing an XML document with Namespaces. I have browsed the community and found plenty of articles of folks having similar issues however, after trying some of those solutions I am just as confused as when I started and just going in circles. I want to understand this. Some of those posted solutions out there seem to indicate I only have to add a blank Namespace attribute to my decorators (Namespace ="") and others show the actual namespace uri being referenced but only for the root element leaving blanks in subsequent elements \ attributes. I am more looking for the education as to 'why'\'when' to use one method over another and an example of how to accomplish this given the XML below. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not too far off.

1. Your `XmlElement` attribute implies multiple `rsids` elements. What you want is a single `rsids` element containing multiple `rsid` elements. The easiest way to do this is using the `XmlArray` and `XmlArrayItem` attributes.
2. The `val` property shouldn't be `static`
3. Due to what looks like [a bug in `XmlSerializer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36163079/1320845), you need to include `Form = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified` in your `XmlAttribute` attribute.

You can also omit most of your `Namespace` properties as they'll be inherited, and `ElementName` doesn't have to be specified explicitly.

Putting all that together:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main")]
public class settings
{
    [XmlArray("rsids")]
    [XmlArrayItem("rsid")]
    public List<rsid> Rsids { get; set; }
}

public class rsid
{
    [XmlAttribute(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public string val { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, if that's all you want then a simple LINQ to XML query would be a lot easier:

```
XNamespace w = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";

var rsids = doc.Descendants(w + "rsid")
    .Attributes(w + "val")
    .Select(x => x.Value);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8X95lg) for a working demo of both approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am closer to understanding how to properly serialize XML. Your code worked perfectly and the .NET Fiddle is pretty cool. I wasn't aware of this website - Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            int[] rsids = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "rsids").Select(x => new  {
                rsids = x.Elements().Select(y => int.Parse((string)y.Attribute(x.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("w") + "val"), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber))
            }).Select(x => x.rsids).FirstOrDefault().Select(x => x).ToArray();

        }
    }

}
```