# Why an XML string cannot be deserialized due to prefixes in root elements?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

I have the XML below:

```
<y:input xmlns:y='http://www.blahblah.com/engine/42'>
    <y:datas>
        <y:instance yclass='ReportPeriod' yid="report">
            <language yid='en'/>
            <threshold>0.6</threshold>
            <typePeriod>predefinedPeriod</typePeriod>
            <interval>month</interval>
            <valuePeriod>April</valuePeriod>
            <fund yclass="Fund">
                <name>K</name>
                <indexName>CAC40</indexName>
            </fund>
        </y:instance>
    </y:datas>
</y:input>
```

That I am trying to deserialize to

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="fund")]
public class Fund 
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName="indexName")]
    public string IndexName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="yclass")]
    public string Yclass { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="instance", Namespace="http://www.blahblah.com/engine/42")]
public class Instance 
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="language")]
    public Language Language { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName="threshold")]
    public string Threshold { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName="typePeriod")]
    public string TypePeriod { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName="interval")]
    public string Interval { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName="valuePeriod")]
    public string ValuePeriod { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName="fund")]
    public Fund Fund { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="yclass")]
    public string Yclass { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="yid")]
    public string Yid { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="datas", Namespace="http://www.blahblah.com/engine/42")]
public class Datas
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="instance", Namespace="http://www.blahblah.com/engine/42")]
    public Instance Instance { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="input", Namespace="http://www.blahblah.com/engine/42")]
public class Input
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="datas", Namespace="http://www.blahblah.com/engine/42")]
    public Datas Datas { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="y", Namespace="http://www.blahblah.com/engine/42", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public string Y { get; set; }
}
```

However, when deserializing the XML above:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Input));
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(File.ReadAllText("file.xml")))
        {
            using(var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
            {
                var instance = (Input)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error due to the `y` prefix...

`There is an error in XML document (1, 1). ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.`

Reading some posts like that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36163079/4636721 it seems that there is maybe a bug with the `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: Where is the ident line : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the exception is that you are passing `stringReader` rather than `xmlReader` to `serializer.Deserialize()`.  You should be passing the XML reader instead:

```
Input instance = null;
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Input));
using (var stringReader = new StreamReader("file.xml"))
{
    using(var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
    {
        instance = (Input)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    }
}
```

(Apparently `XmlReader.Create(stringReader)` advances the text reader a bit, so if you later attempt to read from the `stringReader` directly, it has been moved past the root element.)

You also have some errors in your data model.  It should look like:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="fund")]
public class Fund 
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName="indexName")]
    public string IndexName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="yclass")]
    public string Yclass { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="instance")]
[XmlType(Namespace = "")] // Add this
public class Instance 
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="language")]
    public Language Language { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName="threshold")]
    public string Threshold { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName="typePeriod")]
    public string TypePeriod { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName="interval")]
    public string Interval { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName="valuePeriod")]
    public string ValuePeriod { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName="fund")]
    public Fund Fund { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="yclass")]
    public string Yclass { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="yid")]
    public string Yid { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="datas", Namespace="http://www.blahblah.com/engine/42")]
public class Datas
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="instance", Namespace="http://www.blahblah.com/engine/42")]
    public Instance Instance { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="input", Namespace="http://www.blahblah.com/engine/42")]
public class Input
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="datas", Namespace="http://www.blahblah.com/engine/42")]
    public Datas Datas { get; set; }

    //Remove This
    //[XmlAttribute(AttributeName="y", Namespace="http://www.blahblah.com/engine/42", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    //public string Y { get; set; }
}

// Add this
[XmlRoot(ElementName="language")]
public class Language 
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="yid")]
    public string Yid { get; set; }
}
```

Notes:

- `xmlns:y='http://www.blahblah.com/engine/42'` is an [XML namespace declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace#Namespace_declaration) and thus should not be mapped to a member in the data model.
- The child elements of `<y:instance ...>` are not in any namespace.  Unless the namespace of the child elements is specified by attributes somehow, `XmlSerializer` will assume that they should be in the same namespace as the containing element, here `http://www.blahblah.com/engine/42"`.

  Thus it is necessary to add [`[XmlType(Namespace = "")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.namespace.aspx) to `Instance` to indicate the correct namespace for all child elements created from `Instance`.  (Another option would be to add [`[XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.form.aspx) to each member, but I think it is easier to set a single attribute on the type.)
- A definition for `Language` is not included in your question, so I included one.
- It will be more efficient to deserialize directly from your file using a `StreamReader` than to read first into a `string`, then deserialize from the `string` using a `StringReader`.

Working sample fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OiSutV).