# XNamespace Prefix on XmlAttribute?

Tags: c#, xml

Update: The recommended solution in a comment by @Evk where they linked to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20666023/5311735) worked to solve my issue.

I am trying to generate classes from sample XML, then create an XML file matching the layout. I'm struggling on the namespace prefixes. The target document has namespace prefixes on attributes in the root element which I've not worked with before - for clarity I'm referring to pidx:version and pidx:transactionPurposeIndicator.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pidx:Invoice xmlns:pidx="http://www.api.org/pidXML/v1.0" pidx:version="1.0" pidx:transactionPurposeIndicator="Add" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <pidx:InvoiceProperties>
   <pidx:InvoiceNumber>String</pidx:InvoiceNumber>
</pidx:Invoice>
```

The closes I have gotten as a result is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pidx:Invoice xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" transactionPurposeIndicator="Add" xmlns:pidx="http://www.api.org/pidXML/v1.0">
   <pidx:InvoiceProperties>
     <pidx:InvoiceNumber>NEW_XML_DOC</pidx:InvoiceNumber>
     <pidx:InvoiceDate>2021-10-28T00:00:00-06:00</pidx:InvoiceDate>
  </pidx:InvoiceProperties>
</pidx:Invoice>
```

Here is the generated class and the modifications I've made to it thus far. I commented out the pidx and xsi attribute properties as having those felt wrong. Then I've added the Namespace to the XMLRoot() attribute declaration.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Invoice", Namespace = "http://www.api.org/pidXML/v1.0")]
public class Invoice
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "InvoiceProperties")]
    public InvoiceProperties InvoiceProperties { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "InvoiceDetails")]
    public InvoiceDetails InvoiceDetails { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "InvoiceSummary")]
    public InvoiceSummary InvoiceSummary { get; set; }

    //[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "pidx")]
    //public string Pidx { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "transactionPurposeIndicator")]
    public string TransactionPurposeIndicator { get; set; }

    //[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi")]
    //public string Xsi { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

The method for serializing and writing the file is this:

```
public static void WriteXMLFile(this Models.Invoice openInvoice, string path)
{
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
    settings.Indent = true;

    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("pidx", "http://www.api.org/pidXML/v1.0");
    ns.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Models.Invoice));

    using (var stringWriter = new Utf8StringWriter())
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(path, settings))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, openInvoice, ns);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what problem you have specifying namespaces for attributes (as you seem to do that just fine for elements)? The https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute?view=net-5.0 is no different from XmlElement one...

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20666023/5311735

Comment: Brilliant, @Evk, thank you!

Comment: @Evk good find - did not know about issue when namespace matches element's one... Looks perfect duplicate to me. Codenamecain  - feel free to edit the question to clarify if that did not work so it can be reopened.